# R - summarize factor level for every combination of two other factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `D1` with 4 columns:

- `F1` contains factors `[A, B]`
- `F2` contains factors `[P, Q]`
- `F3` contains factors `[X, Y]`
- `F4` contains numeric values

How can I transform this into a new three columned dataframe, `D2`:

- `F1` and `F2` as before
- `F3` contains the mean of all values in previous rows averaged over all levels of `[X, Y, Z]` and store this in a new dataframe.

I know how to get the mean per single factor level, but I would like to do this for the cross product of two other levels.

**example**
given the dataframe:

```
F1  F2  F3  F4
 A   P   X   2
 A   P   Y   4
 A   Q   X   3
 A   Q   Y   5
 B   P   X   1.5
 B   P   Y   2.5
 B   Q   X   0
 B   Q   Y   1
```

the following dataframe would be outputed:

```
F1  F2  F3
 A   P   3
 A   Q   4
 B   P   2
 B   Q   0.5
```

Ideally this should work irrespective of the number of levels of factors invovled

Comment: It would help if you posted sample input data and expected output from that sample data.

Comment: your attempts and searches didn't return anything useful?

Comment: As my initial rambling attempt to describe the problem shows, it is hard to put in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(F3=mean(F4)) , .(F1, F2)]
#    F1 F2  F3
#1:  A  P 3.0
#2:  A  Q 4.0
#3:  B  P 2.0
#4:  B  Q 0.5
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(F1, F2) %>%
    summarise(F3= mean(F4))
#  F1    F2    F3
#  (chr) (chr) (dbl)
#1     A     P   3.0
#2     A     Q   4.0
#3     B     P   2.0
#4     B     Q   0.5
```

---

```
aggregate(F4~F1+F2, df1, mean)
```

Comment: what is the %>% operator?

Comment: @Tom It is the `pipe` or `chain` operator which unites the arguments together on either side of the operator

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution with library `dplyr` is:

```
library(dplyr)
D1 <- data.frame(F1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
                 F2 = c('P', 'P', 'Q', 'Q', 'P', 'P', 'Q', 'Q'),
                 F3 = c('X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'),
                 F4 = c(2, 4, 3, 5, 1.5, 2.5, 0, 1),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
D2 <- D1 %>% group_by(F1, F2) %>% summarise(F3 = mean(F4))
```

This will replace column F3 with the mean.

The output is as follows:

```
D2
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: F1 [?]

     F1    F2    F3
  (chr) (chr) (dbl)
1     A     P   3.0
2     A     Q   4.0
3     B     P   2.0
4     B     Q   0.5
```

Comment: I meant that you are working with the original data.frame, while their output is an aggregated one, with only four rows. Oh, I see you've switched to `summarise`, but then this repeats part of akrun's answer.

Comment: This is the same as my solution posted several mins earlier

Comment: His was first based on data table. Mine was dplyr. He just added dplyr answer.

Comment: I added dplyr solution before you posted the solution